# Using insertion sort on a singly linked list

Tags: c++, list, sorting, linked-list, insertion-sort

So I have an assignment where I'm giving a random list of number and I need to sort them using insertion sort. I must use a singly linked list. I looked around at other posts but none seem to help. I get what insertion sort is but I just don't know how to write it in code.

```
Node* insertion_sort(Node* head) {
  Node* temp = head_ptr;
  while((head->n < temp->n) && (temp != NULL))
    temp = temp->next;
  head->next = temp->next;
  temp->next  = head;
  head->prev = temp;
}
```

I dont know if this is right or what to do now

Comment: What is `head_ptr`? What if `temp` is `NULL` right away?

Comment: Man, schools are crazy. It'd take me ages to get this right. I use `std::sort`.

Comment: Disclaimer: I'll be downvoting answers that post full code.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Certainly implementing low level algorithms isn't something you need to do all the time, but I'd argue that as a programmer you'd still have to at least 'get it'.

Comment: Is this algorithm supposed to be sorting the whole list? or just inserting one item in a prior-sorted list? Not that it does *neither* correctly, but the name implies you want to feed it a list head and get back a sorted list as a result. Is that correct?

Comment: Im suppose to be sorting the whole list

Comment: Ok. that makes a lot more sense. thanks.

Comment: @Cubic: Sure, I grok it. But I'll be using a reference if I ever need to implement it.

Comment: @Cubic Indeed. I consider utilities like std::sort as things I can use so I don't have to reinvent the wheel over and over; not because I have no idea how to invent the wheel in the first place. You should know how it works if for no other reason than to appreciate just how much work it is saving you.

Comment: You get what insertion sort is, so compare an insertion sort algorithm to the code you've written. You'll see that they're nothing like each other. For a start insertion sort has *two* loops one inside the other. So I would throw away what you've written. Have a book open describing insertion sort as you write your code and try again.

Answer (score 7):

Let's think about how Insertion Sort works: It "splits" (in theory) the list into three groups: the sorted subset (which may be empty), the current item and the unsorted subset (which may be empty). Everything before the current item is sorted. Everything after the current item may or may not be sorted. The algorithm checks the *current* item, comparing it with the next item. Remember that the first item after the current item belongs to the unsorted subset.

Let's assume that you are sorting integers in increasing order (so given "3,1,5,2,4" you want to get "1,2,3,4,5"). You set your current item to the first item in the list. Now you begin sorting:

If the next item is greater than the current item, you don't need to sort that item. Just make it "current item" and continue.

If the next item is less than the current item then you have some work to do. First, save the next item somewhere - let's say in a pointer called temp - and then "remove" the next item from the list, by making current->next = current->next->next. Now, you need to find right place for the removed item. You can do this in two ways:

1. Either start from the beginning of the list, going forward until you find the correct position. Once you do, you insert the item there and you continue your insertion sort. This is the simplest solution if you have a singly-linked list.
2. You go backwards, until you find the correct spot for the item. Once you do, you insert the item there and you continue your insertion sort. This is a bit more involved but can work well if you have a doubly-linked list.

You continue this process until you reach the end of the list. Once you reach it, you know that you have completed your insertion sort and the list is in the correct sorted order.

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 6):

```
struct node {
    int data;
    struct node *next;
};


void insertion(struct node **head) {
    if((*head)== NULL || (*head)->next == NULL) {
       return;
    }
    struct node *t1 = (*head)->next;
    while(t1 != NULL) {
        int sec_data = t1->data;
        int found = 0;
        struct node *t2 = *head;
        while(t2 != t1) {
            if(t2->data > t1->data && found == 0) {
                sec_data = t2->data;
                t2->data = t1->data;
                found = 1;
                t2 = t2->next;
            } else {
                if(found == 1) {
                    int temp = sec_data;
                    sec_data = t2->data;
                    t2->data = temp;
                }
                t2 = t2->next;
            }
       }
       t2->data = sec_data;
       t1 = t1->next;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is the Java Implementation of Insertion Sort on Linked List:

> - Time Complexity: O(n^2)
> - Space Complexity: O(1) - Insertion sort is In-Place sorting algorithm

```
class Solution 
{
    public ListNode insertionSortList(ListNode head)
    {
        // Initialize partially sorted list
        ListNode dummy = new ListNode(0), prev = dummy, current = head;

        while(current != null)
        {
            if(prev.val > current.val)
                prev = dummy;

            // Find the right place to insert current node
            while(prev.next != null && prev.next.val < current.val)
                prev = prev.next;

            // Insert current between prev and prev.next
            ListNode nextNode = current.next;
            current.next = prev.next;
            prev.next = current;
            current = nextNode;
        }
        return dummy.next;
    }
}
```

Comment: This question is tagged C++, not Java.

Answer (score 2):

Wow, I'm sure late to the party huh? Regardless, I would like to throw in my two cents in answering this question. Based on the way you provided your sample code, I am going to assume the following:

1. You are not using OOP principles
2. You already have the singly linked list setup correctly (I'll refer to it as **forward list**)
3. You want the user to use operator '=' when calling the implementation function

To begin, the answer I'm about to give you uses what I like to call the *double pointer technique*! Where you use a double pointer to help you reference two variables at the same time such that you avoid a complicated test case when reaching *nullptr*.

Okay, okay... I am playing fast in lose by calling *pointer-to-pointer* **double pointer**, and I may be tugging your leg by calling it a **technique**! If you have mastery over the concepts of pointers, then what I am about to show you should be quite trivial. I call pointer-to-pointer a *technique*, because rarely anybody talks about it or uses it in their example source code! The following [link](https://blog.semmy.me/post/9809052196/the-pointer-to-pointer-trick) will take you to a blog created by Semmy Purewal that discusses this concept in more detail!

```cpp
forward_list *insertion_sort( forward_list *head )
{
  /// Ensure provided linked list is not empty and has more than one element...
  if( head == nullptr || head -> next == nullptr )
  {
    std::cout << "Error: empty or single element linked list provided!\n";
    return;
  }

  /// Initialize separate variable the houses a growing sorted output...
  forward_list *sorted = nullptr;

  /// Traverse provided singly linked list...
  while( head != nullptr )
  {
    /// Remember current head before popping it off...
    forward_list *current_head = head;

    /// Double pointer for effective splicing of unsorted singly linked list...
    forward_list **trail = &sorted;

    /// Now we pop off the current head...
    head = head -> next;

    /// Iterate through our growing sorted output to figure out where we need to the head...
    while( ( *trail ) != nullptr && ( *trail ) -> data > current_head -> data )
    {
      /// Head does not belong in this current position, move on!
      trail = &( *trail ) -> next;
    }

    /// Insert the head and update our growing sorted output to point to the head...
    current_head -> next = ( *trail );
    ( *trail ) = current_head;
  }

  /// Return our sorted output...
  return sorted;
}
```

There we go, you now have an example implementation of insertion sort that operates wonderfully on a singly linked list! This implementation does not have a messy test case for *nullptr*, because we used a double pointer named **trail** that keeps track of itself and the pointer pointing to our growing sorted output. Thus, as the algorithm iterates through the sorted output, the variable **trail** gets dereferenced at *nullptr*, which holds the last node's **next** pointer!

All in all, I hope you find this answer to be both *helpful* and a little bit more *readable*! I know this question was asked seven years ago and was only active one year ago, but I hope someone finds this somewhat useful. Whelp, I'll be on my way then!

Answer (score 1):

Think about this - if the list is empty, `temp` will initially be `NULL`, so you get undefined behavior when you do `temp->next  = head;`.

Try some debugging, it will surely help. You'll probably either want to keep the previous node as well, so you can insert afterwards, or look 2 nodes forward.

Answer (score 1):

I have coded it using classes instead of struct. Changes could be done but the algorithm would be same.
Code for creating class of node and single link list..

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

class node{
    public:
    int data;
    node* next;
};

class list{
    node* head;

    public:
    list() {
        head=NULL;
    }

    void add(int el) {
        node* newNode=new node();

        newNode->data=el;
        newNode->next=NULL;

        if(head==NULL) {
            head=newNode;
        } else {
            node* temp=head;

            while(temp->next!=NULL) {
                temp=temp->next;
            }
            temp->next=newNode;
        }
    }

//Insertion sort code

    void insertionSort() {
        node* i=head->next;

        while (i!=NULL)
        {
            node* key=i;
            node* j=head;

            while (j!=i)
            {
                if (key->data<j->data)
                {
                    int temp=key->data;
                    key->data=j->data;
                    j->data=temp;
                }
                j=j->next;
            
            }
            i=i->next;
        }
    }

    void display() {
        node* temp=head;

        while (temp!=NULL) {
            cout<<temp->data<<" ";
            temp=temp->next;
        }
    
    }
};
```

For creating main:

```
int main()
{
    list l;
    l.add(2);
    l.add(6);
    l.add(0);
    l.add(3);
    l.add(7);
    l.add(4);

    l.insertionSort();
    l.display();
}
```

Do correct me if not working or the criteria for insertion sort in not implemented correctly.

Answer (score -1):

```
void linked_list::insertion_sort() {
    node * p = head;
    node * currentNode = head->next; // The node that is being compared at the moment.
    node * previousNode = head; // The node previous to the node being compared at the moment.
    //We can return from the sorting if the length of the linked list is less than 2.
    if (p == nullptr || p->next == nullptr) {
        return;
    }

    while (currentNode != nullptr) {
//If the current node is larger than or equal to the largest element of the sorted linked list on the left, we can move to the next element. 
//Helpful for an already sorted array.
        if(previousNode->value<=currentNode->value){
            currentNode = currentNode->next;
            previousNode = previousNode->next;
        }
        else{
//If the element is the smaller than the head element we need to take care of the head element.
            if (head->value > currentNode->value) {
                previousNode->next = currentNode->next;
                currentNode->next = head;
                head = currentNode;
            }else {
                p = head;
                while (p->next != NULL && p->next->value < currentNode->value) {
                        p = p->next;
                }
                previousNode->next = currentNode->next;
                currentNode->next = p->next;
                p->next = currentNode;
            }
        }
        currentNode = previousNode->next;
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Code-only answers are discouraged as they are not helpful for inexperience programmers. Please include an explanation for how this solves the question and how it improves upon the other upvoted answers to this 5 year old question.